# Where can I bind column cell view controls?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

[image: link to image]

I've been Googling for 3 hours, I can't find where to bind these things for Core Data in this textbook I'm reading. I just want to know where to find out where to bind it. I assume it's in the binding inspector after you highlight a column but under value it doesn't show anything like "Col 0 Image View" and for the first column I can't see a section that includes two places to set a binding which needs for an Image View and a Text Field. Below is an excerpt (as well as I can copy it) from the textbook *Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X 4th Edition* chapter 11, page 185.

"Now bind the `value` of each column's cell view control(s), as shown in the following table."

One of the entries in the table is:

**Binding** `value`of Col 0 Image View 
**Bind to** Table Cell View
**Controller Key** Empty
**Key Path** objectValue.photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a day's work of searching and random clicking I found this rather elusive, yet out-in-the open binding. I hope this helps anyone else who might be frustrated.

This is where to find it, you want to click the one that shows what I have circled. Open the bindings inspector and then it'll pop up with objectValue already populated in your key path.

[image: first image]

The first column has two since it has an image view and text view. Make sure to select the appropriate one for whichever one you want bound.

[image: second image]